# How to run javascript after PDF file Download

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, response.redirect

I download a FILE to PDF , everything works. I show a loading Image before running the process as it can take several seconds or minutes to collect data from DB to make the file .

```
<p>
    <asp:LinkButton Height="40" OnClientClick="showLoading();"
        OnClick="btnDownload2_Click" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" ID="LinkButton1"
        Text="Click Here to Download List of Registered Students per course">
        <span style="text-align:center"> Download List&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <img id="Img2" style="display:none" src="../../images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" />
    </asp:LinkButton>
</p>
```

The issue is when the file gets downloaded how can i change the `Img2` back to original style. If it was not `Resonse.Write` it would automatically have switched to original style after button event finished.

This is the file download Process ....(end part)...

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+reportName+".pdf");
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.End();
Response.Close();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `btnDownload2_Click` is a javascript function you created, right? And you download it using Ajax? If so, at the response, you could do something like `document.getElementById('Img2').setAttribute('src','/path/you/want/');`

Comment: Nope btnDownload2_Click  is a server side function...

Answer (score -1):

Just add a query string value to indicate success, then on page load check for it and add a class.

So when a file download has finished:

```
Response.Redirect("yourUrl" + "?Success=true");
```

Then on your page load:

```
if (Request.QueryString["Success"] != null)
{
    LinkButton1.CssClass += " file-downloaded";
}
```

Comment: I use Response.Write So show download prompt so not sure how i would use Response.Redirect here

Answer (score -1):

Your button has runat server, btnDownload2_Click it's a method from codebehind and you are making a postback to download .

On the same method at the finish just add:

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("change_image", "document.getElementById(""Img2"").src=""../../images/loader-finish.gif"";");
```

Comment: After the finish it is to Download  pdf file so Response.Write occurs which clear all other javascript functions ..

Comment: Use this : http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com


It does many things like :


Fire a javascript function when all uploads are complete.


View upload progress of individual files and entire process.

Comment: I need for downloading :)